# Optimization with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I learn best by example, so forgive my impudence.

My knowledge on calculus go as far as one variable only, so I struggle to find an application of total derivatives. Suppose I was to find the minimum values for $(x,y)$, does multivariate calculus prove handy?

Suppose I was to find the minimum value for $(x,y)$ in $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x - a_1)^2 + (y - a_2)^2} + \sqrt{(x - b_1)^2 + (y - b_2)^2} $$
where $a_1,a_2,b_1$ and $b_2$ are arbitrary constants. How do I apply the concept of total derivatives to find the minimum value of $f$?

I know that the maximum/minimum value for any given function $g(x)$ is $x$ when $g'(x)=0$, but does that necessarily translate when working with multiple variables? If so, how do I wrap my mind about it?

Comment: Okay, but suppose I was given an arbitrary function $z(x,y)$, how do I find the min/max values for $x,\ y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative). [Local extrema will be critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)):
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = 0$$

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ will not be eliminated in both derivatives, it now becomes a system of equations, yes?

Comment: @JohnGlenn, right. And the condition is *necessary*, not sufficient.